# what is zsh: exec format error in redhat?

Tags: redhat

zsh: exec format error... This is the error I was getting when trying to execute a large application. I am using redhat Linux. Please let me know what is the best thing to do. I have searched online. I could found the correct solution for this. Please do not hesitate for asking simple question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; try asking this on the [Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) site instead, and [include more information](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `uname` command to check the appropriate architecture of your installed RHEL system;

```
uname -m
```

Use above command and try accordingly.